# number of pairs of integers (x, y), with x ≤ y, from the set of numbers {1, 2, . . . , 2016}, that special mean of x and y is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For positive real numbers x and y, define their special mean to be average
of their arithmetic and geometric means. Find the total number of pairs of
integers (x, y), with x ≤ y, from the set of numbers {1, 2, . . . , 2016}, such
that the special mean of x and y is a perfect square.

Comment: "[...] to be **average** of their arithmetic and geometric means." Average in what sense? Arithmetic? Geometric? Harmonic?

Comment: There are $\lfloor\sqrt{2016}\rfloor$ obvious pairs, plus some more

Comment: @dp1611 please if possible try to describe better the content of the question in the title, thanks!

Comment: By "average", do you mean arithmetic mean? So that the special mean of $x$ and $y$ is $\frac{\frac{x+y}2+\sqrt{xy}}{2}$?

Comment: yes u r right @Arthur

Comment: thnks for suggesting     @iadvd

Comment: stated clearly in the question @martini

Comment: Has my answer helped you? Have you made progress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the special mean of $a$ and $b$ is $\displaystyle \frac a4 + \frac b4 + \frac 12 \sqrt {ab} = (\frac{\sqrt a}{2} + \frac{\sqrt b}{2})^2$